# what is this dropdown looking layout called?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

IThere is a really cool layout feature in the QuizUp app where when you click a button it shows a menu under that button and pushes everything else down, here is what I mean:

This: http://m.imgur.com/p5iqS5c

To this: http://m.imgur.com/WS931xS

I'm wondering what it is called in terms of java/android so that I can look it up and learn how to implement it.

Comment: ExpandableListView created with Custom Layout Screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called `ExpandableListView` feature in `Android`.

See this link to get Start [Android Expandable List View Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)